# How to Change the Azure Files Snapshots created time by Azure File sync?

Tags: azure, synchronization, snapshot, azure-files

I'm setting up a new Azure File Sync with a file server, 
and there are some snapshots created by Azure File Sync every day.
I want to find a solution to change the snapshot creation time. 
What do I need to set the command/Azure File Sync?

This is for a normal windows 2016 File Server,  I registered the `server endpoint "E:\"`and the `cloud endpoint "testsharefile1"` into one sync group.

I had tried many times, sometimes there will be `one snapshot created by Azure File Sync every day`, and sometimes there will be `two snapshots (almost same time) created by Azure File Sync`.

I expect the Azure Files' snapshot can be created by Azure File Sync every day at the scheduled point time, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: To clarify, Are you referring to snapshots on the Azure file share? May I know in which region are you using?

if you want regularly scheduled snapshots, you should use Azure Backup, which provides snapshot scheduling.

Comment: I use the region of southeast Asia.  Thanks for your attention, I know Azure Backup could do that, but I think if I can use the Snapshot created by Azure File Sync, then I have no need to use Azure backup because now I am using the Azure File Sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure File Sync used to create share snapshots daily to ensure files that are tiered can be accessed. These share snapshots are no longer needed by Azure File Sync so we stopped creating them when v7 released.  To ensure you have a backup of the Azure file share, they should either [manually create snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-snapshots-files) or use [Azure Backup.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-files)

Note: Azure File Sync does still create a share snapshot when a new server is added to a sync group. Once the files have been downloaded to the new server, the temporary snapshot is deleted.